# Invisible buttons are not sent

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

How to send invisible buttons?

I tried inserting `ephemeral=True`, but the buttons was not sent at all. (Only embed with drop menu worked)

```py
#Embed with Drop Menu
mrv = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=DD_review(), ephemeral=True)

#Buttons
mrvb = await mss.send(view=B_review(), ephemeral=True)
```